# Solve collisions outside of the normal physics cycle

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unity3d-2dtools

Is there a way to test and resolve collisions outside of the usual collision system?

There is a situation where I want most of the game objects to collide using the basic filters system unity provides.

But a very special group of objects (within 4 different layers) will behave differently and collide in some situations differently.

I will add child objects with circular triggers to serve as the broad phase, then I would like to call the engine's collision resolution only if the objects are supposed to collide.

How should I proceed to trigger the collision resolution manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Physics2D.BoxCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.BoxCast.html), [Physics2D.CircleCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html), [Physics2D.OverlapArea](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapArea.html) or [Physics2D.OverlapCircle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) to check collisions outside of physics' simulation routine.

You may resolve collisions based on data received from methods above. AFAIK Physics2D is adopted Box2D, which is open-source. So you may find solution for coliisions in its source code.